# What is the relative effectiveness of self initiated versus therapy approaches to repairing damaged body schema?

Tags: reference-request, abnormal-psychology, motor

Several studies discuss the damaged [body schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_schema) of amputees and people suffering from [CRPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_regional_pain_syndrome).
By damaged [body schema](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1350799/) I mean where the body their mind constructs doesn't match up with the body that is objectively there. Ie. limbs perceived as there or not there despite evidence, [CRPS](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18625661), extension/contraction of perceived limbs differing from reality.

The types of damage I'm most interested in are pain resulting or allegedly resulting from a disruption of the body schema itself such as [phantom limb pain](http://www.ted.com/talks/vilayanur_ramachandran_on_your_mind.html), [autoscopy/out-of-body experiences](http://brain.oxfordjournals.org/content/127/2/243.short) and [CRPS](http://brain.oxfordjournals.org/content/130/10/2671). Phantom limb sensation also interests me. Mostly, **the important distinction I wish to draw is healing through the power of one's own volition or through the help of others, as diametrically opposed as I can get it.**

**What is the relative effectiveness of self-initiated versus therapy provided by others in repairing a damaged body schema?**

Comment: (1) Could you clarify what you mean by damaged body schema? What types of damage are you interested in? (2) Would you be able to add a couple of the references to the studies that you've read to make the question more useful for others?

Comment: I think that's clearer. cheers.

Comment: have you seen the american tv show house?

Comment: I'm enjoying the subtext in the bounty box: "The question is widely applicable to a large audience...Quite a niche question, sure..." Just poking fun, but I do agree! It is quite a niche question, but it is still a large enough niche to be well worthwhile. :) Good luck though! Anyone aware of research (or even anyone with enough personal experience to weigh in authoritatively) on this specific subtopic would definitely deserve the bounty.

Comment: @NickStauner haha! I hadn't even put those two together, you're right. Agreed! I've not got much rep here, but there's at least enough to throw at this question. I'm still very interested in an answer and this is the *only* SE question I've ever asked that didn't get *any* replies.

Comment: @LitheOhm http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbE2ch-9ZFc it may be a little offensive.

Comment: I see we're not the only ones who find it interesting, so you might just get an answer sooner or later. However, I wish you luck because I fear it might be needed. The niche is large enough, but small compared to many others, both in terms of the disorder and in terms of the therapeutic issue in question. Combining both the damaged body schema and self-vs.-other-initiated therapeutic contexts makes this a likely candidate for truly original research; I worry it hasn't been done yet. I do hope I'm wrong though! In the meantime, would more general research on the therapeutic issue interest you?

Comment: @NickStauner uh did you see my link..there is a guy named Vilayanur S. Ramachandran who specialized in this kind of stuff.

Comment: @LitheOhm if your interested in a mirror box answer i'll make one but its pretty simple.

Comment: Didn't see it; sounds promising! BTW, I suspect the mirror box method doesn't relate much to "the important distinction I wish to draw." However, if any research exists on a moderator of that method's effectiveness such as, "`Patient personally initiates or adheres to mirror box therapy regimen` vs. `Therapist recommends patient to, or guides patient in mirror box therapy`," that would seem to be exactly on-topic as far as I understand the topic! I'm just guessing at what the OP will say here though; I don't mean to put words in his mouth!

Comment: @caseyr547 awesome link! Didn't know House covered that one. I am familiar with Ramachandran actually. It's hard not to find something by him when researching phantom limb sensation/pain. The mirror box is very fascinating and definitely outlines the core of body schema problems (proprioceptive sense, etc.). If you can find sources highlighting individual tasks (using alone, no need for 'pro' advice) versus physician-guided it would be within the scope I'm aiming for.

Comment: @NickStauner Ramachandran is definitely the who's who in phantom limbs, at least that's the impression I got from my research project (especially this [Ted Talks](http://youtu.be/Rl2LwnaUA-k) video). It's part of what sparked this question; If the mirror neuron effect exists within us, then is it **necessary** (I won't touch the *advisable* part) to depend on others for care.

Answer (score 1):

**Background**

[Phantom Pain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_pain) happens when a limb is lost over the course of one's life or missing since birth. Essentially the brain generates pain and sensations for the missing limb. It is thought to be a psychological problem brought on by inherit physiological traits of the human brain. As a psychological problem it is subject to conscious and unconscious retraining. No treatment has as yet proven completely effective against phantom pain.

[Mirror Therapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_box) is one scientific [clinically useful](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21326041) treatment for phantom pain developed by [Vilayanur S. Ramachandran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilayanur_S._Ramachandran). It normally involves the use of a mirror box in later stages of rehabilitation.

A mirror box was featured on the American Television show "House" as a treatment for a war veteran. This [clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbE2ch-9ZFc) illustrating the fictional use of a mirror box from that episode is inaccurate as it shows the mirror box as a instant cure all however it does accurately describe the process by which the mirror box is used. The clip may be considered somewhat offensive because House is always somewhat offensive.

> In a mirror box the patient places the good limb into one side, and the stump into the other. The patient then looks into the mirror on the side with good limb and makes "mirror symmetric" movements, as a symphony conductor might, or as we do when we clap our hands. Because the subject is seeing the reflected image of the good hand moving, it appears as if the phantom limb is also moving. Through the use of this artificial visual feedback it becomes possible for the patient to "move" the phantom limb

-[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_box)

Mirror therapy has been proven by fMRI imaging to extort spatial attention.

> In this first study on the neuronal correlates of the mirror illusion in stroke patients we showed that during bimanual movement the mirror illusion increases activity in the precuneus and the posterior cingulate cortex, areas associated with awareness of the self and spatial attention. By increasing awareness of the affected limb the mirror illusion might reduce learned non-use. The fact that we did not observe mirror-related activity in areas of the motor or mirror neuron system questions popular theories that attribute the clinical effects of mirror therapy to these systems.

-[The neuronal correlates of mirror therapy: an fMRI study on mirror induced visual illusions in stroke patients](http://peer.ccsd.cnrs.fr/docs/00/57/87/09/PDF/PEER_stage2_10.1136%252Fjnnp.2009.194134.pdf)

Attention (which is in this case not the same word as "pay attention") is as [William James](http://psychclassics.asu.edu/James/Principles/prin11.htm) deﬁned "withdrawal from some things in order to deal effectively with others.". Or as [Shaun P. Vecera and Matthew Rizzo](http://aegean.psychology.uiowa.edu/Faculty/Vecera/lab/papers/vecera&rizzo_neuroclinics.pdf) defined "The processes that permit an organism to choose some environmental inputs over others".

Spatial attention again defined by [Shaun P. Vecera and Matthew Rizzo](http://aegean.psychology.uiowa.edu/Faculty/Vecera/lab/papers/vecera&rizzo_neuroclinics.pdf) is "restricted to visuospatial attention—those attentional processes that select visual stimuli based on their spatial location".

**Conclusion**

Mirror therapy typically begins in a doctors office. A doctor trains a patient during in or out patient rehabilitation to look into the mirror and clench or move both the present and missing limb. After the technique has been proven useful to the individual it can be done [at home](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3468806/) without a doctor supervision and minimal training with the [same overall results](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22378591) for both upper and [lower body](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/23677239_Self-delivered_home-based_mirror_therapy_for_lower_limb_phantom_pain). Home based treatment results in [nearly equal compliance](http://www.hindawi.com/isrn/rehabilitation/2012/926784/).

It is my hypothesis that increased prevalence of virtual and augmented reality will allow for new kinds of spatial attention treatments for those with multiple amputations and chronic arthritis effecting both hands.